# webpack - splitting vendor and global application code

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack and am looking to be able to split my code into the following bundles:

1. Vendor code e.g. all globally used packages
2. Global application code e.g. code shared by at least x number of modules across the application
3. Page specific bundles

So far I have managed to separate page specific bundles from vendor and global application code using the common chunks plugin:

```
 new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        filename: 'common.bundle.js',
        minChunks: 20
      }),
```

However I want to be able to split this common bundle into vendor.bundle.js and global.app.bundle.js

Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this, alot of the examples are purely about splitting vendor and app.

Thanks in advance